# array adapter shows wrong items unable to plot google maps route

Tags: android, google-maps

Lemme slap my code right here...

```
public class Index extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
    public static String[] account;

    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    String[][] mobileArray = {
            new String[] {"150 Goyeau St, Windsor, ON N9A 6J5","Product 1","N/A","3:30pm"},
            new String[] {"2000 Talbot Road West, Windsor, ON N9A 6S4","Product 2","N/A","4:00pm"},
            new String[] {"350 City Hall Square W, Windsor, ON N9A 6S1","Product 3","N/A","4:30pm"}
    };

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            hideSystemUI();
        }
    }
    private void hideSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tVDriver = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tVDriver);
        tVDriver.setText(account[0]);
        final TextView tVSpecial = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tVSpecial);
        final TextView tVProduct = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tVProduct);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview, mobileArray[0]);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lVDelivery);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter, View v, int position, long id){
                tVSpecial.setText(mobileArray[position][2]);
                tVProduct.setText(mobileArray[position][1]);
            }
        });
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;
        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this);
        enableMyLocation();
    }
    private void enableMyLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
        } else if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationClick(@NonNull Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Current location:\n" + location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            return;
        }
        if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            enableMyLocation();
        } else {
            mPermissionDenied = true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        if (mPermissionDenied) {
            showMissingPermissionError();
            mPermissionDenied = false;
        }
    }
    private void showMissingPermissionError() {
        PermissionUtils.PermissionDeniedDialog
                .newInstance(true).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }
}
```

I am attempting to plot a path in google maps (and automatically zoom in my location when activity is loaded.) by tapping an item in the array.

Problem being is that the arrayadapter is listing the first arrays items. Programmatically it makes sense but its not what i want. I wanted to display the first item in the second array for all first arrays. Meaning i want just the address to display in the arrayadapter.

i know the problem lies right here.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview, mobileArray[0]);
```

But what part of the array do i call to have these displayed correctly?

Second question is how can i zoom into my location when this activity is loaded and how can i plot the path? I tried 2 different ways and one of them had errors that prevented it from working and the other didnt display it at all.

Here is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/in_the_weeds"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVNull"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="#80FFFFFF"
        android:text="Driver"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVDriver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="#80FFFFFF"
        android:text="No Driver"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lVDelivery"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#80FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVProductNull"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lVDelivery"
        android:background="#80FFFFFF"
        android:text="Product"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVProduct"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="165dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lVDelivery"
        android:background="#80FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="1g - Bubba Hash" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVSpecial"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tVProductNull"
        android:background="#80FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create a new array that contains just the addresses. But the better approach would be to create a custom class (let's call it `Product`), which just contains getters and setters. Then you change the `ArrayAdapter<String>` to an `ArrayAdapter<Product>`. Custom ArrayAdapters are pretty easy:

https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial

EDIT: Here's the bad solution I mentioned. The other one would take too long for me to type out (but you should really learn it because it's a super-common task in Android):

```
public class Index extends AppCompatActivity implements 
GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener, 
GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback, 
ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
public static String[] account;

private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;
private GoogleMap mMap;
String[][] mobileArray = {
        new String[] {"150 Goyeau St, Windsor, ON N9A 6J5","Product 1","N/A","3:30pm"},
        new String[] {"2000 Talbot Road West, Windsor, ON N9A 6S4","Product 2","N/A","4:00pm"},
        new String[] {"350 City Hall Square W, Windsor, ON N9A 6S1","Product 3","N/A","4:30pm"}
};

String[] addressArray = new String[mobileArray.length];
for (int i=0; i<mobileArray.length; i++) {
    addressArray[i] = mobileArray[0][i];
}


@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        hideSystemUI();
    }
}
private void hideSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tVDriver = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tVDriver);
    tVDriver.setText(account[0]);
    final TextView tVSpecial = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tVSpecial);
    final TextView tVProduct = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tVProduct);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview, addressArray);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lVDelivery);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter, View v, int position, long id){
            tVSpecial.setText(mobileArray[position][2]);
            tVProduct.setText(mobileArray[position][1]);
        }
    });
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;
    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this);
    enableMyLocation();
}
private void enableMyLocation() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
    } else if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onMyLocationClick(@NonNull Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Current location:\n" + location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        return;
    }
    if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        enableMyLocation();
    } else {
        mPermissionDenied = true;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    if (mPermissionDenied) {
        showMissingPermissionError();
        mPermissionDenied = false;
    }
}
private void showMissingPermissionError() {
    PermissionUtils.PermissionDeniedDialog
            .newInstance(true).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

}

Comment: Would you be able to demonstrate by editing your post using my code? Im trying to understand how it looks.

Comment: thanks, i didnt even think of that. Maybe im working too long. Regardless. i had to slap it in the oncreate and change the 0 and i to display the correct information. Thank you. Are you able to direct me to a working route plot google map api? I can never get it working right when i tap on an array item.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used that part of the API.

Comment: Thanks anyways, i gave you the correct answer given that you did answer my question partially.